# Installing MatLab R2015a on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: software-installation, 15.10, matlab

When I run ./install in the terminal it outputs:

```
Preparing installation files ...
Installing ...
Finished
```

but it doesn't actually open the installer window for MatLab. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

entered these commands:

```
 sudo chmod -R 777 ~/"folder with matlab" 
 sudo ./install
```

This made the installer window appear and installation proceeded normally.

Answer (score 3):

`./install -mode silent -inputFile installer_input.txt`

You want to make a copy of the template installer_input.txt and fill in your values for FIK and license server, etc. (assuming license server licensing)
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/96403-how-can-i-install-and-activate-matlab-on-a-unix-linux-machine-without-using-the-x-window-system-x-s

Alternatively you can use `ssh -X host` and run the gui installer from a machine with xwindows.